# Java(TM) Platform SE binary consuming high amount of internet data (Maven in background)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The high amount of internet usage gets triggered only when I work on eclipse with maven or when there is any maven project in the workspace.
with glasswire, I confirmed it was "maven.map.fastly.net" where It was downloading a ton of data.

I have less amount of daily data so it will help if someone could provide a suggestion on how to stop it or is there a setting that I need to turn off while I am working with maven?

[image: data consumption]

Comment: Maven tends to download dependencies. Check if you can run offline which should avoid all data access, but if it's missing anything that it would usually just download it will fail instead. This way you can at least control when Maven is allowed to download anything.

Comment: it will consuming your data, but it will consume first time when you have added new dependency. if your dependency would be exist in .M2 direcotry then it will reuse it and will not going to download again.

Comment: Eclipse might be downloading maven central index.

Comment: Thanks for such quick responses. I learned that disabling all download options worked for me .  Windows-> preferences -> maven -> deselecting all downloadable options. And maven first build takes time